# Why does the integral $\int_{-\infty}^ \infty \frac{1}{x^2}dx$ diverge?

Tags: calculus, integration, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

The integral $\int_{-\infty}^ \infty \frac{1}{x^2}dx$ according to many websites diverges. But, by manual calculation, the answer is clearly $0$. Why is this the case?

Comment: How did you get $0$?

Comment: If I'm not wrong, by evaluating the integral and directly placing the limits. The OP however, realized his/her mistake

Comment: You cannot get answer $0$ by integrating a positive function!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized it's because the value at x = 0 does not exist. It approaches infinity from both sides at x = 0.

Comment: To be more detailed, the most general antiderivative $-1/x+C$ takes $C$ to be [*locally constant*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_constant_function), so its value can change at the $x=0$ asymptote. This also means, for example, $\int_{-1}^2\frac1xdx$ is undefined.

Comment: Yes, the integral of $1/x^2$ is well worth remembering as an example of what can go haywire when integrating across a singularity: the function here is always positive (except, of course, at $x=0$, where the problem lies), so one would expect any integral, which measures the area beneath the curve, to be positive, yet in this case it formally calculates to $0$.

Answer (score 2):

One must be extremely careful and must pay close attention while applying the [Fundamental Theorem Of Calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#Corollary) (Note that the function **must** be continuous if you want to apply this theorem directly) . This is a common example where many (including myself) made mistakes.

A better way to write this integral would be : (To avoid confusion)
$$\lim_{a\to 0^-}\int_{-\infty}^a\frac{1}{x^2}\mathrm{d}x+\lim_{b\to 0^+}\int_{b}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^2}\mathrm{d}x$$
Upon solving, we get:
$$\lim_{a\to0^-}-\frac{1}{x}\bigg|_{-\infty}^a+\lim_{b\to 0^+}-\frac{1}{x}\bigg|_{b}^{\infty}$$
$$=\lim_{a\to 0^-}-\left(\frac1a-\frac{1}{-\infty}\right)+\lim_{b\to0^+}-\left(\frac1{\infty}-\frac1b\right)$$
$$=-\lim_{a\to 0^-}\frac1a+\lim_{b\to0^+}\frac1b$$
Which is clearly divergent.

Answer (score 0):

Because when $x$ approaches zero (from either side), $y$ approaches infinity in a way that is not converging. You can look at how $1/x^2$ approaches the positive $y$-axis the same way $1/x$ approaches the positive $x$-axis, both are diverging!